# Asp.net Server application is working on localhost, but not in Azure (Unhandled exception rendering component: ExpectedJsonTokens)

Tags: c#, asp.net, azure, asp.net-core, blazor

I have created a web application and it is my first time to bring it live into Azure. I have followed all the steps and got SQL with all the connection strings and so on. I am able to access my application from web address. However once I am trying to login or register from web, I am getting an exception.

What I have done:

Opened `appsettings.json` in my solution in Visual Studio and added connection string to Azure SQL. Then run my application in Debug mode on my computer and tried to register a new user => everything worked! So If I am accessing Azure SQL from my computer (https://localhost:7113/login) everything works fine, I am able to read and write into database. If I do the same from https://xxx.azurewebsites.net/login I am getting errors mentioned below. Any ideas why it is so and how to fix?

Has it something to do with setting ap API routing?

My launchSettings.jason:

```
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:25391",
      "sslPort": 44337
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "MaDashWeb.Server": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      },
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7113;http://localhost:5113",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development"
      }
    },
    "Docker": {
      "commandName": "Docker",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "launchUrl": "{Scheme}://{ServiceHost}:{ServicePort}",
      "publishAllPorts": true,
      "useSSL": true
    }
  }
}
```

I am having solution model build this way: Client, Server, Shared

> crit:
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.Rendering.WebAssemblyRenderer[100]
> Unhandled exception rendering component: ExpectedJsonTokens Path: $ | LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.
> System.Text.Json.JsonException: ExpectedJsonTokens Path: $ |
> LineNumber: 0 | BytePositionInLine: 0.  --->
> System.Text.Json.JsonReaderException: ExpectedJsonTokens LineNumber: 0
> | BytePositionInLine: 0.    at
> System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ThrowJsonReaderException(Utf8JsonReader&
> , ExceptionResource , Byte , ReadOnlySpan`1 )    at System.Text.Json.Utf8JsonReader.Read()    at System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[MDashWeb.Shared.Authorization.LoginResult,
> MDashWeb.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null]].ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& , JsonSerializerOptions
> , ReadStack& )    Exception_EndOfInnerExceptionStack    at
> System.Text.Json.ThrowHelper.ReThrowWithPath(ReadStack& ,
> JsonReaderException )    at
> System.Text.Json.Serialization.JsonConverter`1[[MDashWeb.Shared.Authorization.LoginResult, MDashWeb.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].ReadCore(Utf8JsonReader& , JsonSerializerOptions , ReadStack& )    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[LoginResult](JsonConverter , Utf8JsonReader& , JsonSerializerOptions , ReadStack& )    at System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ReadCore[LoginResult](JsonReaderState& , Boolean , ReadOnlySpan`1 , JsonSerializerOptions , ReadStack& ,
> JsonConverter )    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.ContinueDeserialize[LoginResult](ReadBufferState&
> , JsonReaderState& , ReadStack& , JsonConverter ,
> JsonSerializerOptions )    at
> System.Text.Json.JsonSerializer.d__65`1[[MDashWeb.Shared.Authorization.LoginResult, MDashWeb.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()    at System.Net.Http.Json.HttpContentJsonExtensions.<ReadFromJsonAsyncCore>d__4`1[[MDashWeb.Shared.Authorization.LoginResult,
> MDashWeb.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()    at
> MDashWeb.Client.Services.Implementations.AuthorizeApi.Login(LoginModel
> loginModel)    at
> MDashWeb.Client.Pages.Authentication.Login.OnSubmit()    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task
> task)    at
> AntDesign.Form`1.d__128[[MDashWeb.Shared.Authorization.LoginModel,
> MDashWeb.Shared, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
> PublicKeyToken=null]].MoveNext()    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task
> task)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.Forms.EditForm.HandleSubmitAsync()
> at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.ComponentBase.CallStateHasChangedOnAsyncCompletion(Task
> task)    at
> Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree.Renderer.GetErrorHandledTask(Task
> , ComponentState )

I am wondering is this something similar?: https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/29162

---

I have AuthorizeApi.cs in CLient project with following:

```
public async Task<RegisterResult> Register(RegisterModel registerModel)
{
  HttpResponseMessage response = await this.HttpClient.PostAsJsonAsync("api/Authorize/Register", registerModel);
  return await response.Content.ReadFromJsonAsync<RegisterResult>();
}
```

Then in Server project I have Controller with following code:

```
[Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
[ApiController]
public class AuthorizeController : ControllerBase

...

[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> Register([FromBody] RegisterModel model)
{
  ApplicationUser newUser = new ApplicationUser
  {
    UserName = model.Email,
    Email = model.Email,
    FirstName = model.FirstName,
    LastName = model.LastName,
  };

...
```

Comment: From the error its difficult to point the issue, Please share the line of code that is showing in the Error message. My first impression is are you trying to deserialize any user claim/ login details in your startup?

Comment: LaunchSettings is for VS, not Azure. You have an API call to the wrong URI, Blazor Hosted then serves up HTML instead of a 404.

Comment: @HenkHolterman I think so too, but what exactly is wrong and how to fix? I have added my codes to my question. Could you save my day? Trying to go live for the first time

Comment: Track the api/Authorize/Register call in the Browser Dev Tools. Compare the exact URL there and figure out what it should be. Issue could be in  index.html,  `<base href= >`

Comment: I can see a 500 coming back. 1) handle the exception in the Client. b) is this the first time your Server hits the Db ?

Comment: @HenkHolterman b) I have just created Azure Server and DB, so I guess answer is yes. I run same app on my localhost and just created a user successfully in Azure DB, but as you have already checked 500 is returned once running from Azure Server. For point 1) you mean handle exception to avoid these page error and need for reloading the page? I will do so.

Comment: @HenkHolterman Ok! After 6 hours of fighting with this issue, I have finally discovered a Log Stream! So just go to Azure into your Webb App and navigate to Log Stream. It iill tell you all your exceptions... Mine was Avatar byte[] that was pointing to wrong file path... Here are some details about Log Stream: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/731457/aspnet-core-api-published-default-page-getting-500.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank You [Henk Holterman](https://stackoverflow.com/users/60761/henk-holterman) for pointing the OP in the right direction. Posted your valuable discussion as an Answer to help other community members.

Glad the user [LG3](https://stackoverflow.com/users/18640084/lg3) for resolved his issue by going to the Log Stream which shows all the exceptions and their details which shows you that you're pointing to an incorrect file path and mentioning the [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/731457/aspnet-core-api-published-default-page-getting-500.html) gives the resolution of this kind of errors and as the same suggested by the Henk Holterman user in another way to check the **exact URL** from the browser dev tools of **api/Authorize/Register** call.